# Will naming a column 'count' cause problems in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I would like to name a column 'count', but I'm worried it could cause problems as I already have a lot of queries written that use `` count(*) as `count ``

Will that cause problems?

Comment: You should avoid using reserved/keywords if you can help it.

Comment: Using reserved words as column names is always a bad idea, as it requires more work to avoid conflicts. With that being said, this question is inappropriate for SO, as you're asking for opinion (good/bad) and discussion, both of which the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) mention as being a poor fit for this site's design. Voting to close for that reason as not constructive.

Comment: The question is "will it cause problems?". I don't see how that's an "opinion" question. It either will or will not cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not recommend it, as it's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), but if you must, you can escape it with backticks:

```
SELECT `count` FROM `table` WHERE 1
```

As far as what you already have, you can still use both queries. The `COUNT(*) AS 'count'` will return a single row with a single column, 'count'. The `SELECT 'count'` way will return it as a normal column.

Also, note that I used ' instead of ` in the last sentence, just because SO uses ` to denote code.

All in all, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Salil this is an answer and should not be a comment.  The OP wants to know if it's a good idea or not.  The answer given is that it's not really a good idea, but shows how it is actually legal.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Josh's answer.  You can use pretty much anything inside the backquotes, including spaces I believe -- but *don't* do that!

Semantically speaking, I would ask what the benefit is of having a field named 'count'.  What exactly is it counting?  I would suggest that you get in the habit of being more specific with your field names.  For example: `limb_count`, `error_count`, `num_attempts`, `num_failures`...

When you are joining multiple tables in large queries, the SQL will read much clearer if your field names are not ambiguous.